# EditText Reducing the layout above

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-edittext

I've looked for similar problems but couldn't finally solve mine

I have an *editText* on the bottom of my activity and a *viewPager* including a *listView* above it.

The problem is that the *listView* is minimized when I focus the editText or even hidden in landscape. When I click on the editText that it gets focused, it reduices the *Fragment's* height including the listView.

Despite the fact that my *viewPager* is constraintly attached to the *editText* and that the viewPager's *Fragment* is height set to match_parent, there is a huge gap between the *listView* and the bottom *editText*.

The only thing I see between the bottom editText and the listView is the viewPager's Background. So it's actually the fragment's layout that is resized.

I've noticed that the problem disappears when I set the editText's height to a constant value. The fact is that I need to let it on wrap_content because I'm using multilines property so I need the editText to expand.

What is completely crazy is that the gap between the two elements depends on the editText's hint lenght. In the screenshot below, it's set to "Message" but if I set a longer hint like "New message" the gap will be lot bigger !

Here is part of the activity's layout

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/LayoutMsgBar"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/navigationBar" />


<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/LayoutMsgBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/darkGrey"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:theme="@style/msgBar"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/viewPager">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextMsg"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:hint="@string/nv_msg"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"

        android:maxLength="2000"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"

        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/sendButton"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/moreButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

and the Fragment layout that is called by the view pager

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/messagesListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


</ListView>
```

[What I have before I swipe or click on the editText](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvGaW.png)

[What I get after click on editText then reduce it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XDIA.png)

I've set the viewPager's background color to orange. It's not hidding the listView, it's below it.

My point is basically that my listView stays attached to the bottomBar, so to the editText

If you have an idea that would be awesome !

Comment: Try putting that edittext inside a framelayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved it by replacing my bottom bar constraintLayout by a linear layout.
I don't get it, the constraints were right, but that worked.